# React Native Exception thrown while executing UI Block: A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time

Tags: ios, reactjs, user-interface, native, block

I'm having issues with this. I can't seem to find a solution. I'm trying to implement a dialog box. It works well on Android. But currently having troubles with iOS. Please help :(

```
    Exception thrown while executing UI block: A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <RCTView: 0x7fe0e7e62ad0; reactTag: 355; frame = (0 0; 414 896); layer = <CALayer: 0x600003a877c0>> is associated with <UIViewController: 0x7fe0e7c4e450>. Clear this association before associating this view with <UIViewController: 0x7fe0e7c56060>.

__44-[RCTUIManager flushUIBlocksWithCompletion:]_block_invoke
    RCTUIManager.m:1192
__44-[RCTUIManager flushUIBlocksWithCompletion:]_block_invoke.489
__RCTExecuteOnMainQueue_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
start
0x0
```

[image]